# Is there any predefined field on quotline which calculates product quatity for amendment quote

Tags: quote, cpq, quotelineitem, quote-template

when amending the contract, If we increase quantity for allready subscrption products,

When generating invoice its showing total quantity, not newly added(i.e increased) quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SBQQ__EffectiveQuantity__c"

Effective quantity used in computing totals. Same as quantity unless the product is block-priced or covered by the Slab discount schedule, or an existing subscription.

For amendment quotes, this field is equal to (Quantity) - (Prior Quantity).

Comment: Is this additional information for the question? If so please edit your question and add it to that not post it as an answer. See [ask] and [answer] for how to do this.